# Usb mouse response slowly on first time boot-up

Tags: usb, mouse, centos

I am using Cent OS . 
When I start Cent OS first time in the day. The usb mouse works very slowly nearly with nonresponse. 
But when I restart my system it works fine. 
It is happening every day. 
 What can be the problem ?

Comment: a regular mouse works fine ?

Comment: @Shark I don't have one. 
But I tried with 2-3 usb mouse same problem I faced.

Comment: Have you tried to unplug and reconnect the mouse when the issue occurs?

Comment: @Michale k yes. then it don't works at all after plunging. I have to restart my system.

Answer (score 0):

There could be number of reasons...

- Try download latest driver for your mouse
- Maybe there are too many applications running at the background as soon you start Cent OS. It make sense why your Usb mouse response slowly...
- Buy a new mouse